# How to add an viewPager as header to ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I also used the `addHeaderView` method to add the [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) as header.

But when I scroll the ViewPager , the ListView also scrolls.

How can I prevent the ListView to not receive the touch event when I scroll the ViewPager. How can I override the onInterceptTouchEvent in ListView ?
return false ?

Comment: The other way is don't set the ViewPager as your Listview header instead set the ViewPager above the Listview.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have solved the problem by now, but anyways:

You can use the following implementation of [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), we just need to override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` as you are already aware of it:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public MyViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return False;
    }

}
```